# How to store an entire list in a single row of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple list of different lengths such as the following:

**List 1**

```
['In addition to new financing, a coalition of organizations will provide technical assistance on a wide range of activities, including the mapping of restoration opportunities, securing further financing, and providing catalytic support for the implementation of restoration efforts on the ground.',
 'The main actors in implementation of restoration are farmers, herders, resource user groups, local leaders and other actors in rural communities, along with supporting stakeholders such as the private sector, NGOs and government agencies working at different levels.']
```

**List 2**

```
['African Union Development Agency (AUDA-NEPAD)',
 'Bioversity International',
 'Catholic Relief Services (CRS)',
 'CIFOR',
 'CIRAD',
 'Conservation International (CI)',
 'Deutsche Gesellschaft für Internationale Zusammenarbeit (GIZ)',
 'Ecoplanet Bamboo',
 'EverGreening Alliance',
 'Food and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations (FAO)',
 'Global Water Partnership Southern Africa',
 'Heinz Sielmann Stiftung',
 'International Center for Tropical Agriculture (CIAT)',
 'International Tree Foundation',
 'International Union for Conservation of Nature (IUCN)',
 'Jane Goodall Institute (JGI)',
 'Justdiggit']
```

I want to store all the entries in each of these list as a single entry into a columns row as these list represent a category and all the elements in the list are grouped under a specific category.

Like this:

```
Description | Organizations |
  List 1    |    List 2     |
```

I have tried `df[Organisations] = List2` but this treats each item in the list as an entry for a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the following:

```
#Create an empty dataframe with the columns you want
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Description","Organizations"])

#Fill the columns
df.loc[0,"Description"] = list1
df.loc[0,"Organizations"] = list2
```

Output

```
Description                                         | Organizations
____________________________________________________|_______________
[In addition to new financing, a coalition of ...   |[African Union Development Agency (AUDA-NEPAD)...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
df['Description'] = ','.join(list1)
df['Organizations'] = ','.join(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List1= [contents]
List2 = [contents]
lstTotal = []
for i in range(len(List1)):
     newSection = [List1[i],List2[i]]
     lstTotal.append(newSection)
```

this will output

```
lstTotal = [[description1,organization1],[description2,organization2],etc...]
```